# Viewing events in jQuery $.subscribe $.publish calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on some existing javascript that uses $.publish and $.subscribe jQuery calls.

I have an event trigger, something like $.publish("savePlugin"); As expected it fires several functions that are subscribed to "savePlugin". This is all working great, but I think some of them are firing twice. How can I get a list of all the functions subscribed to this event to see if there are duplicate entries? Is there any way for me to edit that list?

All I want is a call like this: $.showMeWhoIsSubscribedToThis("savePlugin");
I can't seem to find my way to it, or anything like it. You help is much appreciated.